# Bash-Scripting: what does ${VARIABLE[number]} mean if VARIABLE is not an array?

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, expansion

I know that there are arrays in bash-scripting. For example:

```
JOBS=("JOB1", "JOB2", "JOB3")
```

Then one can refer to, say, JOB2 as follows:

```
${JOBS[1]}
```

In a bash script I recently encountered a normal (non-array) variable:

```
JOB="XYZ"
```

Later in the script, this variable was referred to as follows:

```
${JOB[0]}
```

and:

```
${JOB[1]}
```

Since JOB is not an array, I do not understand what ${JOB[number]} is expanded to.

Is this just a programming mistake? Or is there some construct regarding normal variables I am not aware of?

Comment: Without seeing the entire script it's hard to tell, but it sounds like a mistake.  Writing `${JOB[0]}` would simply return the same thing as `$JOB`, and any other index would return an empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bash` doesn't have array values at all; it provides array *syntax* to use with names that have an `array` attribute set:

```
$ a=()
$ declare -p a
declare -a a=()
```

The `-a` in the output indicates that the `array` attribute is set on `a`, having been set implicitly by the preceding array assignment.

For such variables, the name-plus-index acts as a sort of "virtual" name, and like any other name, expands to the empty string if the name doesn't actually exist, as is the case with `${JOB[1]}`. A side effect of the implementation is the `$foo` and `${foo[0]}` are generally equivalent, whether or not `foo` has its array attribute set.

Answer (score 0):

I believe newer versions of Bash support one-dimensional arrays and the syntax can be seen in the following link as follows :
[Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html)

If Variable is not an array, ${Variable[Number]} will work only for Number=0 but not for any other number as ${Variable[0]} and $Variable - both are same.